# Unable to convert MD5 hash to Array Buffer in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic2, cordova-plugins

MD5 Sample 84e575e8930be31609406816658033cb. which needs to be converted

```
commandValue = Md5.hashStr(commandValue);
console.log("MD5 after generation "+commandValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is one way, you cannot decrypt.

If you want to hash an Array Buffer, JSON.stringify it, if the md5 function does not accept it.

```
commandValue = Md5.hashStr(JSON.stringify(value_to_hash));
```

Regards

Tom